# Remove duplicates in multiple columns SQL with where clause

Tags: sql, pandas, database

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT day, A, B, C 
FROM MyTable
WHERE day = 20230815
  AND A < 4
```

I have rows that agree on multiple columns, i.e. a row will have columns `A, B, C` all the same. I want to completely remove rows where this happens (I don't want to keep the first row, I want to completely remove them all).

I've seen some answers online about joining the table to itself, but I don't know how to incorporate this with my `WHERE` clause and also how to completely remove the duplicates.

I'm asking for the SQL equivalent of

```
MyTable = MyTable.drop_duplicates(subset=["A", "B", "C"], keep=False)
```

in Pandas.

Comment: Any NULL values involved? Show us some sample table data and also _specify_ the expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images. no links.)

Comment: If null values are involved they do not change the question as asked. The expected result is specified by the pandas command ```drop_duplicates``` that I have shown @jarlh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the Pandas equivalent would be

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C) > 1 AS is_duplicated
    FROM
        MyTable
)
WHERE NOT is_duplicated
```